# where is the wrong in this syntax of calling http request get

Tags: java, http, get, httprequest

I have this call (from the browser)

```
http://serverName:8081/cmp-mg-?sub_x?=7
```

**and it returns 200 response**

and I want to call do that request from my web service:

this is my web service:

```
public Response sendMT2(@BeanParam MT mt) throws IOException {
        try {
            HttpHost host = new HttpHost("serverName", 8081);
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET",
                    "/serverp/sam?" + mt.getURLParameter());
            System.out.println("/cmp-mg-xconn-http-webapp/sam?"
                    + mt.getURLParameter());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(host, request);
            String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler()
                    .handleResponse(response);
            return Response.ok(responseString).build();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            throw e;
            // return Response.status(500).build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
            // return Response.status(500).build();
        }
    }
```

but I am getting error

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
```

what is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error myself.

before sub-r_mob .. i had `?` instead of `&`